# Passing value with numeric format

Tags: rexx

i have problems regarding passing value with formatting issues.
The description i have put in the codes as i am having problem passing my `PreEditedCheque` in my code for the `if ValidateMMonCheque <> MM` part. The output for `if length(RawChequenumber) = 15` will be in 1 digit instead of 00001 ( example)

```
MM = HostGetFLD('','MM')
YY = HostGetFLD('','YY')
PreEditedCheque = substr(RawChequenumber,11,5)

ValidateMMonCheque = substr(RawChequenumber,7,2)

if ValidateMMonCheque <> MM Then    *From this statement* 
Do
   PreEditedCheque = substr('00000',1,5)  *This part where those 0 can't be properly shown if pass to the next statement*
   EditedCheque = '00'||'2'||'0'||YY||MM||'00'||PreEditedCheque 
   rc = message(2,2,EditedCheque)
End


if length(RawChequenumber) = 15 Then  

   EditedCheque = '00'||'2'||'0'||YY||MM||'00'||PreEditedCheque + 1 *Second statement if <>MM ran, this part, the PreEditedCheque will be not in 00001, it will be 1. 

rc = PanSetCtlData('PREVIEW',EditedCheque)
```

Comment: What was the input, What output are you getting and what where you expecting ???

Comment: i expect the output to be 00001(5 digit) instead of 1( just one digit), the input actually pass from rawchequenumber variable.

Comment: The problem is the `+` in the second statement, this converts it into a numeric expression, Ross's suggestion of using the Right function should work

Comment: yeah, you are right , Bruce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is to have the cheque number padded to the left with zeroes in a 5-character field.  The [Right() function](http://www.rexxinfo.org/html/functions.html#right) is your friend:

```
Right(PreEditedCheque, 5, '0') /* "1" -> "00001" */
```